# Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge Proofs: zk-snarks and zk-stark

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, security, interactive-proof-systems, authentication

I read up on an abstract example of ZKPs (the cave and the door), but I'm trying to understand NIZKs (specifically zk-snarks and zk-stark). All the examples I can find online seem to have some interactive component even when trying to explain nizks. I don't particularly fancy reading some 300 pages of papers to understand this topic. Is there some sort of example (perhaps abstract) a la the cave for regular ZKPs that I could use to understand nizks?

Comment: Very roughly speaking, you make an interactive proof non-interactive by using trusted randomness, which can be used to simulate the interaction.

Comment: There is a question on crypto.SE about understanding NIZKs with very good answers (they're more technical than an allegory, but "abstract-length"): https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14365/what-is-a-non-interactive-zero-knowledge-proof

Comment: @eru-cs - that seems to be somewhat in line for what I'm looking for, but that only goes over zk-snarks esque techniques. Would there be anything similar for zk-stark?